# Post-Publish Script under Publish Profile XML for IIS getting called before actual publish

Tags: visual-studio, iis, msbuild, publish

I am trying to figure out how `Pre-Publish` and `Post-Publish` scripts work with `MSBuild` deployment for `IIS` from `Visual Studio 2019`.

Below is my `customprofile.pubxml` file:

[image]
When I publish the output windows prints messages but Post-Publish also happened before actual publish.

[image]

Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps or not and let us know any feedback about it. And we are willing to help you further:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Actually**, `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` are used for ClickOnce publish(windows project publish) rather than Asp.Net web project publish.

What you shows does not prove the target `AfterPublish` execute under the build process but only list in the build log.

Please set **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Diagnostic` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run** to get the detailed log.

There is [a similar case about this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/602198ff-17a3-43f3-9beb-26221e4fe6c7/afterpublish-target-not-working).

=======================================

I suggest you do this test:

**Test**

I write an error target like:

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Command="123">
    </Exec>
  </Target>
```

If the project detects the error during publish, it means the project has the system targets.

**The Winform project detects the error while the web project does not.**

**In fact**, when you click **Publish** button on web project, it actually executes `WebMSDeployPublish` and since web publish does not contains **AfterPublish** and **BeforePublish** targets, you should specify a dependenttarget on them.

**Solution**

Use these:

```
<Target Name="BeforePulish" BeforeTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
.....

</Target>

<Target Name="AfterPublish" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">

.......

</Target>
```

===============================================

**Update 1**

Sorry for not listing all the tips about the issue in detailed.

The problem should be divided into two cases:

===============================================

**Net Framework project**

For **Net Framework web project publish**,

**Actually** in `Net Framework` project, there is no obvious system default targets called `BeforePublish` and `AfterPublish`. The **GatherAllFilesToPublish** is the core publish step and also the last target that executes under the publish process.

[image]

**However, all targets under the net framework web publish process run after the generation of the publish folder which means that they are all like BeforePublish.**

**It** is the special feature of **Net Framework Web Publish**. Coping all files into publish folder is after the last target of the publish process. So you cannot make a custom target that depends on the last default system target. It is quite annoying. At least by default, you can't make any custom targets to make any changes to publish files in the **Net Framework Web Publish** case.

You can see that there is no other system custom target runs after generating the publish folder.

[image]

**However**, I have one solution for you and it might be a bit complex. And it can do a job after the generation of the publish folder.

**Solution**

**1) First**, you should install a nuget package called [MSBuild.Extension.Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Extension.Pack/) which is an extra extension for msbuild tasks.

It has a task called `AsyncExec` which can executes with the following targets. While it is running, it will continue to execute the next steps of publish. You only need to make the command sleep for a while and wait the publish folder to be generated so that you can modify that publish folder.

**2)** write this under `xxx.pubxml` file:

```
<Target Name="custom step" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">

    <AsyncExec Command="powershell.exe sleep 2;powershell.exe -file xxxxx"></AsyncExec>
          
</Target>
```

The sleep time is up to the the size of your project and how long it takes to publish the folder.

And this function works well in my side.

==================================================

**Asp Net Core project publish**

**For Asp Net Core web project publish,**

It has `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` system default target. And AfterPublish target is after copying all files into the publish folder so that you can use that system target directly as well. And it is also the last target of the net core web publish process. And this is equivalent to `_TransformWebConfigForAzureAuthentication` of Framework Publish process.

[image]

The first line of the screenshot and the previous content is the process of generating the **publish** folder. You can check that the copying all files into publish folder is before the `AfterPublish` target.

**And** you can find that for `dotnet publish`, there is a real target called `AfterPublish` and it runs after the generation of the **publish** folder.

**However**, It is just that the default target of this system cannot be overwritten, it can only be depended on.

So you should use like this:

```
<Target Name="custom step1" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">

<Exec Command=""/>

</Target>

<Target Name="custom step2" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
 
<Exec Command=""/>

</Target>
```

**To be honest**, `dotnet web publish` has made greater optimizations compared to `framework web publish`, and it does solve this problem, and it does not make any improvements to the old `framework web publish`, so we have to seek other workarounds.

**Conclusion**

**Winform project publish**, it has `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` targets and you can overwrite them directly.

**Net Framework web publish**, it does not have `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` targets  and you should use other ways.

**Asp Net Core web publish**, it has `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` targets and they cannot be overwritten and you should use custom targets that depends on them.

Comment: Thanks. It works great for `BeforePublish` events. But what is the target name that executes after publish has completed ?

Comment: First, I am curious about what your project type is, a asp net core project or a asp net framework project?

Comment: Actually in net framwork project, there is no obvious system default targets called `BeforePublish` and `AfterPublish`. The `GatherAllFilesToPublish` is the core publish step and also the last target that executes under the publish process. However, you should note that, if you want to modify these files under the publish by that target, I am afraid that it cannot be done by that way. However, all targets under the `net framework web publish` process run after the generation of the publish folder which means that they are all like BeforePublish.

Comment: So it seems that there is no possibility that does a job like `AfterPublish` under framework web publish. It is the special feature of net framework web publish. Coping all files into publish folder is after the last target of the publish process. So you cannot make a custom target that depends on the last default system target. It is quite annoying. At least by default, you can't make any custom targets to make any changes to publish files in the Framework Web Publish case.

Comment: But for `asp net web project publish`, sorry for that not listing this tip at first, it has `AfterPublish` and `BeforePublish` system target. And `afterpublish` target is after copying all files into the publish folder so that you can use that system target as well. And it is also the last target of the net core web publish process. So it meets our requirements without any problems.

Comment: But in ASP Net Core Web Publish, `AfterPublish` can't be overwritten, it can only be dependent, so you can only use: `<target Name="custom step" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">...</Target>`

Comment: I have update my answer. See `update 1`. You can check it and I hope it could help you:) –

Comment: Hey buddy , Thanks for your help. It works like a charm. `<Target Name="AfterPublish" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">   
    <AsyncExec Command="powershell.exe sleep 20;powershell.exe Start iexplore.exe "></AsyncExec>   
  </Target>`